# Fancybox giving white page in ifame on IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, fancybox

I am using

```
<a href="content.aspx?id=21" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Content</a>
```

to show this content in iFrame in fancybox.

But in IE7 fancybox coming white blank box. Any body have any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If using the latest version of fancybox (v2.1.4) try disabling the `iframe` `preload` in your custom script like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    iframe : {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a right solution, but iframe preload can be usefull in many cases. The only case we need to disable iframe preloading is under IE7 and older ugly browsers, so I suggest to replace the

```
iframe: {
    preload: false
}
```

by

```
iframe: {
   preload: !(document.all && !document.querySelector)
}
```