# Fancybox afterClose event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm having a problem using the fancybox API after Close.

I open the function when people click on this:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe btn" href="myurl.php"></a>
```

The javascript behind this is:

```
$('.fancybox.iframe')
    .fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    padding: 0,
    overlay: {
        locked: false
    },
    beforeClose: function () {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

And it never reload the page when I close it. Can somebody help me? Thank you !

Comment: There is an error in the HTML-class, the period (.) should be replaced with a space( ):
<a class="fancybox fancybox iframe btn" href="myurl.php"></a>

Comment: @AdrianForsius : is not an error, `fancybox.iframe` is a valid special *class* for fancybox v2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some clarification to avoid further confusion:

Based on your html

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe btn" href="myurl.php"></a>
```

1. Use the `afterClose` callback (not an `event`) instead of `beforeClose`. For further reference check [Tips & Tricks](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful) => No.11
2. The *class* `fancybox` is used to bind the selector to fancybox so your initialization code should look like this

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $('.fancybox').fancybox({
           arrows: false,
           padding: 0,
           helpers: {
               overlay: {
                   locked: false
               }
           },
           afterClose: function () {
               location.reload();
           }
       });
   }); // ready
   ```
3. The (valid) `fancybox.iframe` *class* tells fancybox the type of content it should handle, but you don't use it to bind the selector to fancybox.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vo3dta8n/7)**

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.x

Comment: Thank you, this helped me and thanks for adding that .iframe isn't needed anymore, thought it had too :)

Comment: Hey JFK, it's working correct like it should, but since I removed .fancybox.iframe in the jquery code the lay-out has totally changed. If I add .fancybox.iframe in the jquery the page doesn't reload after closing the fancybox. Do you have a tip ? Thanks

Comment: Small note, can't find the overlay property in the spec

Comment: @Thempower : I never said your don't need the `fancybox.iframe` class; you need it to tell fancybox to use an iframe but you don't use it to bind that selector to fancybox, does it make sense?. Please check numeral 3 of my answer. Also, you may need to set `preload: false` for the iframe, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16777146/1055987 for further reference.

Comment: @Kenneth : It does exist but is a subset of the `helpers` API option. I updated my answer with the correct code and the jsfiddle reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$('.fancybox.iframe').fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    padding: 0,
    helpers: { overlay : {closeClick: false} },
    beforeClose: function () {
        parent.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

(Note that the syntax is different between version 1 and 2 of fancybox. The above is for fancybox2)

Comment: you use `parent.location.reload(true);` if (and if only) you want to reload the parent **from** an iframe, but in the OP's case, fancybox is opening in the main page so it's not needed.

Comment: I guess afterClose: function () { location.reload(); } will do the same as beforeClose: function () { parent.location.reload() }. Both will work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onClose` event:

```
$('.fancybox.iframe')
.fancybox({
    arrows : false,
    padding: 0,
    overlay: {
        locked: false
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        location.reload(); 
    }

});
```

According to the API there is no `beforeClose` event, but there is `onClose`

http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: The OP seems to be using [fancybox v2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and `beforeClose` is a valid API option.

Comment: ...anyways, `onClose` is not a valid API option for fancybox v1.3.x either. It should be `onClosed`