# Fancybox with another event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm having a problem with my fancybox button, I got a button that launches an iframe, this is the code for the button:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe btn btn-green" href="url.php?id=45">Open More Information</a>
```

As you can see it has 4 classes, first 2 to open the fancybox, the last 2 for my css. What I would like to see is that when you click on the button, that the class btn-green removes, then you can see that you already clicked on it.

```
$('.fancybox.iframe').fancybox({
    arrows: false,
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        $("body").css({
            'overflow-y': 'hidden'
        });
    },

    afterClose: function () {
        $("body").css({
            'overflow-y': 'visible'
        });
        $(this).removeClass("btn-green");
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, can somebody help me? Thanks in adventage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to bind fancybox to the `.fancybox` *class* and not to `.fancybox.iframe` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25884667/1055987) (No. 2 and 3)

Second, you can refer to *`this`* using `this.element` inside of any fancybox callback so try :

```
afterClose: function () {
    if (this.element.hasClass("btn-green")) {
        this.element.removeClass("btn-green");
    }
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3yL3xg69/)**