# Using afterClose event with Fancybox3

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

How can I create an afterclose event with FancyBox3? I'm using afterClose event with the second version of fancybox but i'm trying to upgrade to fancybox3 and the instructions say to put the options in "data-options" attribute.

Here's what i tried:

```
  <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="http://www.example.com" href="javascript:;"
     data-options='{
                   
                afterClose  : function() {
                    location.href = "http://www.google.com";
                }
                   }'>
```

and also:

```
<script>
        $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterClose  : function() {
                    location.href = "http://www.google.com";
                }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: So I went to the documentation, than I cliked on Options and scrolled to see all the available `data-options` and than I got to the point where it says: `See Documentation/API/Events for more information` where there's use of functions callback inside of `afterClose`. - so go to https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api and scroll to **Events**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884088/fancybox-afterclose-event-not-working

Comment: @user9263373 not a duplicate. the thread you linked is for FancyBox2 which is very different.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I also tested the method on this page but it didn't work (see edit). Is there a problem with my syntax or something?

Comment: Ok, well regardless you're initializing it wrong.  You're trying to code a callback in your html which is clearly incorrect.  You need to initialize it in your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd snippet should work, see this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQmBZy?editors=1010

HTML

```
  <a data-fancybox="test" data-type="iframe" data-src="https://codepen.io/about/" href="javascript:;">
    External page
  </a>
```

JS

```
$('[data-fancybox="test"]').fancybox({
  afterClose  : function() {
    alert('Done!');
    location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  }
});
```

I have put `alert('Done!')` to see that callback executes. Google will prevent to load itself into an iframe, therefore you will see just blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The code into the HTML attributes won't work as you expected, because it's just a simple text but not a real js function, so to make it work you shoul put the code into the js file, and you are missing something, so please try this

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src  : '#hidden-content',
    type : 'inline',
    opts : {
        afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
            console.info( 'done!' );
        }
    }
});
```

As the documentation says: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api